# How can I change the file sorting of VS Code to be decimal-number-sensitive?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my project I have files labeled as such day1.txt, day2.txt, day3.txt, etc.

Now in my normal file system they are listed in the correct order:

```
day1.txt
day2.txt
....
day10.txt
day11.txt
```

In VS Code they are listed like so:

```
day1.txt
day10.txt
day11.txt
day2.txt
day3.txt
```

Is there a setting somewhere to change this? It is driving me mad.

I've given the settings a search and I didn't see any obvious parameter to change that would affect this.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes there is a way.

In your **Settings** (**File → Preferences → Settings**) search for: `explorer.sortOrder`

A small pen will appear on the left side of the setting. Select the way you want to sort the files. There are five options available:

1. Default
2. Mixed
3. Files first
4. Type
5. Modified

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do this in only specific directory (e.g. /src and its children)?

Comment: For `.go` files, the `type` option will allow your test files to be listed after your code files.

Comment: Is it possible to reverse the order? My filenames begin with a date and I want them in descending order with the most recent date on top.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no option that will allow you to sort all of the open editors alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there's no such option as of yet, but there's already a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5066).